# Cant do a pull request across forks so how do I get my changes in?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-merge, git-fork

So Im new to Git, hence a lot of my terminology might be off here

1. So there is a Main repository, lets call it "Mainline"
2. My teammate and I forked Mainline to develop features independently . Lets call these "teammatefork" and "myfork"
3. Ocassionally we perform a pull request on our forks to add our changes into Mainline
4. Recently I added a bunch of code to "myfork" which is essentially code to build a test harness. We decided to fork "Mainline" again to "TestHarness" to commit this stuff
5. I just realized I cant perform a pull request on "myfork" to merge changes into "TestHarness"

Is the right thing here to do a 'rebase'? - im not quite sure, but it sounds right. Essentially I want to get my changes from myfork into the TestHarness fork and both of these are forks of Mainline

And then I would like to go back 2 revisions onto my fork, so Im back where I began before adding the test harness code

Can someone point out what the git magic is required to do this?

Comment: I don't understand step 4. Why do you need another fork?

Comment: Hi Ismail, the test harness commit was large. We had many scratch files in many folders, so the automation involved uploading those files into our remote database, as a test scenario, so we may use that data to continue building our features. Since we didnt want to clutter up the main repo with the scratch files, we thought having a separate fork may be ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you have 4 repositories:

- "Mainline"
- "MyFork"
- "TeammateFork"
- "TestHarness"

You have commits on "MyFork" that you want to "move over" to "TestHarness".

First of all, you may want to rethink the way you are handling forks. Are your TestHarness changes that large that it requires a new repository?

If you are sure that you want to continue with your path, I think I would do as follows:

I would first go to your "TestHarness" repository and add your "MyFork" as a remote repository and fetch its data:

```
git remote add myfork myfork_url
git fetch myfork
```

Then I would [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) your two commits from your "MyFork" repository:

```
git cherry-pick commit_1_hash
git cherry-pick commit_2_hash
```

Now you should have your two commits on your "TestHarness" fork.

Go back to your "MyFork" and then move back two steps as follows:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Note that this will delete your changes permanently on your "MyFork" fork. You can remove the `--hard` if you want to keep them.

At any time if you want to see the current state of your repository try

```
git log --graph --decorate --all
```

Comment: Perfect! Yes you have understood my situation exactly and your solution fit my problem perfectly - thanks!  Yes the test harness commit was large. we had many scratch files and many folders, so the automation involved uploading those files into our remote database, as a test scenario, so we may use that data to continue building our features. Since we didnt want to clutter up the main repo with the scratch files, we thought having a separate fork may be ideal